# jquery popup value to display check box dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want is after pressing submit button, data gets append in the screen. I had mentioned 3 check box in a div in the below html. Simultaniously, these 3 check box should dynamically bind near by the entered value.

```
<div id="dynamic">
     <td>
          <span class="delete_icon">x<div id="output"></div>
     </td>
     <td>
          <input id="firstaid" onclick="addtreatment();" type="checkbox"/>
          FirstAid needed
     </td>
     <td >
          <input class="sickbay" onclick="addtreatment();" type="checkbox"/>
          Sent to Sick bay
     </td>
     <td>
          <input class="ambulance" onclick="addtreatment();" type="checkbox"/>
          Ambulance
     </td>
</div>
```

[see my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Sivaram2287/r8fzD/4/)

Comment: You're missing a `</span>` here. And I don't see that code in your "demo".

Comment: how to dynamically display a check box on click of a button

Comment: Oh, so, *that* was your question?

Comment: yes sir,please see my fiddle finally the data entered in the popup is diaplaying in the web page.While diaplaying it should take that check box also

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code is a mess. No ended `</span>`, no `<table>` and `<tr>` while using `<td>`...

Anyway, you can add this `<div id="dynamic">` in your HTML and hide it.
Then, on your submission, you can add a clone of it (if you can have more than one) and show it. But then, you shouldn't use an `id` and should use a `class` instead.

You have an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/r8fzD/5/ (but you should really modify that HTML...)

Comment: This is what i expected,is any way to display eack check box and its label in a separate <td>.Please